# How to order the Ubuntu Phone?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Yes, of course, I want that Ubuntu Phone.

Where is the order now button?

Answer (score 8):

If you want a phone running Ubuntu, follow this:

Please, register yourself over http://www.ubuntu.com/phone/register to be the very first.

Quote from the link:

> We are all excited about Ubuntu for phones, but it will take some time to get into the marketplace. If you leave us your email and country details, we will let you know when there is any news. We expect to only email you a couple of times and promise not to spam you.

Answer (score 4):

As *[@Braiam](https://askubuntu.com/users/169736/braiam)* pointed out, you cannot *buy* it because there is no phone on the market right now.

What you can do is help to the project *making a reservation* of the phone or *making a donation*.

**For further information see [here](http://www.indiegogo.com/projects/ubuntu-edge).**

Comment: It's worth pointing out that that indiegogo isn't a store, so that's a page where you can **donate** money to Canonical, and *if they successfully build that phone*, they will give you one.